# How to make this JS link work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put a site link in my site and I don't want to show it in the status bar, so I used this code below but it's not clickable.

```
<a rel"nofollow" href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='http://sitelink">text</a>
```

And, is the `rel"nofollow"` work with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="#" onclick="location.href='http://sitelink'">text</a>
```

- `rel` is an attribute so use an `=`
- use `#` in the `href` so that the link does target the current page
- in the onclick you have a mess with the quotes, you forgot the closing `'`

But instead of misusing an `a` tag you could also use a `button` or `span` for your purpose:

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://sitelink'">text</button>
```

Comment: I tried it, it's work when i directly click on it, but when i use the option "open in new tap" or "open in new windows" it's just giving me "site.com/#", i want to make it work through all clicking options.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work, The browser executes the href part if you use the "open in new tab" function. but you could disable the functionality "open in new tab" when you use a span instead an a-tag

Comment: Well, thank you so much .. i think i need to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="Javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.location='http://sitelink'">text</a>
```